# gdallocationinfo from C++?

Tags: gdal, coordinates, c++

I need a C++ API to convert x,y Image Coordinates in their native projection to output image pixel,line coordnates.  I see the gdallocationinfo documentation, but no API for it.

Where in online GDAL doc I look ...or do I have to write my own?

Comment: I think I answered your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/gdal-c-api-to-convert-text-file-of-coordinate-points-to-raster-pixel-line/31281#31281

Comment: could you find its c++ api?